# RSA Encryption Decryption in Android

Tags: android, rsa, public-key-encryption, encryption

I am implementing a demo for RSA Encryption and Decryption in Android. I can Perform Encryption very well, but In Decryption I get an Exception: `>>java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA`.

```
    KeyPairGenerator kpg;
    KeyPair kp;
    PublicKey publicKey;
    PrivateKey privateKey;
    byte [] encryptedBytes,decryptedBytes;
    Cipher cipher,cipher1;
    String encrypted,decrypted;

    public String RSAEncrypt (final String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException 
    {
        kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(1024);
        kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
        publicKey = kp.getPublic();
        privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
        encrypted = new String(encryptedBytes);
        System.out.println("EEncrypted?????"+encrypted);
        return encrypted;

    }

    public String RSADecrypt (final String result) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException 
    {

        cipher1=Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        decryptedBytes = cipher1.doFinal(result.getBytes());
        decrypted = new String(decryptedBytes);
        System.out.println("DDecrypted?????"+decrypted);
        return decrypted;

    }
```

And I am calling the function from here:

```
encrypt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        { 
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                    try
                    {
                        RSAEncrypt rsaencrypt=new RSAEncrypt();
                        rsaencrypt.RSAEncrypt(name);

                        result=rsaencrypt.RSAEncrypt(name);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        System.out.println("Result:"+result);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            }
        });

        decrypt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        { 
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                {
                    try
                    {
                        RSAEncrypt rsadecrypt=new RSAEncrypt();

                        rsadecrypt.RSADecrypt(result);

                        ans=rsadecrypt.RSADecrypt(result);
                        System.out.println("Result is"+ans);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ans.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        System.out.println("Exception is>>"+e);
                    }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In RSA you should use the public key for encryption and the private key for decryption.

Your sample code uses for encryption and decryption the public key - this can not work.

Hence in the decryption part you should initialize the cipher this way:

```
cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
```

Furthermor your code has a second significant bug:

You are converting a byte array with binary content to a String.

**Never ever convert binary data to a String!**

Strings are for string characters, not binary data. If you want to pack binary data into a String encode it to printable characters for example using Hex or Base64.

The following example uses the hexadecimal encoder fro [org.apache.common.codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) package - a third party library with has to be installed.

```
public byte[] RSAEncrypt(final String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(2048);
    kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
    System.out.println("EEncrypted?????" + new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHex(encryptedBytes)));
    return encryptedBytes;
}

public String RSADecrypt(final byte[] encryptedBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    decryptedBytes = cipher1.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
    decrypted = new String(decryptedBytes);
    System.out.println("DDecrypted?????" + decrypted);
    return decrypted;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..You are Right..I had done Mistake in That..But Now I am getting Exception>> System.err(416): java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA

Please Help me..Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Thanks for that. Just one remarks: keys are symmetrical. So You can either encode with public then decode with private (make sure to whom you send encrypted data) , OR, encode with private, then decode with public (to make sure who sent you the encrypted data). Doing the 2 (with 2 different key set), allow you to enforce both 'from who' and 'to whom' security aspects.

Comment: The "encode with private" case in known as signature. But you should never directly sign data - always sign only the has otherwise you may run into some attacks (see IT security literature).

Comment: always sign only what?

Comment: "always sign only the hash" (SHA-256 or SHA-1 or ...)

Comment: System.out.println("EEncrypted?????" + org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(encryptedBytes)); should be Replaced with System.out.println(new String (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(encryptedBytes))); because there is a library issue. for further info see https://github.com/jscep/jscep/issues/19

Comment: @Kiran Maniya considering the linked issue report your comment is also wrong, because it uses `encodeHexString()` instead of `encodeHex()` as mentioned in the issue.

Comment: Just to have the terminology right [Confidentiality : Encrypt with Public-Key and Decrypt with Private-Key] [Signature: Sign with Private-Key and Validate with Public-Key] - Is this correct?

Comment: @Franklin correct. Keep in mind that usually you don't use asymmetric crypto for encrypting large data, only for encrypting a generated symmetric key (e.g. AES key).

Comment: This answer is awesome thank u so much for posting it!

Answer (score 14):

My class:

```
package com.infovale.cripto;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

public class RSA {

KeyPairGenerator kpg;
KeyPair kp;
PublicKey publicKey;
PrivateKey privateKey;
byte[] encryptedBytes, decryptedBytes;
Cipher cipher, cipher1;
String encrypted, decrypted;

public String Encrypt (String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException 
{
    kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(1024);
    kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());

    encrypted = bytesToString(encryptedBytes);
    return encrypted;

}

public String Decrypt (String result) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException 
{           

    cipher1=Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    decryptedBytes = cipher1.doFinal(stringToBytes(result));
    decrypted = new String(decryptedBytes);
    return decrypted;

}

public  String bytesToString(byte[] b) {
    byte[] b2 = new byte[b.length + 1];
    b2[0] = 1;
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, b2, 1, b.length);
    return new BigInteger(b2).toString(36);
}

public  byte[] stringToBytes(String s) {
    byte[] b2 = new BigInteger(s, 36).toByteArray();
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(b2, 1, b2.length);
}
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is an example for Android of:

- generating a private/public RSA key pair
- encrypting a string
- decrypting the encrypted string

These methods deal with all the base 64 encoding/decoding.

```
    public void TestEncryptData(String dataToEncrypt) {
        // generate a new public/private key pair to test with (note. you should only do this once and keep them!)
        KeyPair kp = getKeyPair();

        PublicKey publicKey = kp.getPublic();
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
        String publicKeyBytesBase64 = new String(Base64.encode(publicKeyBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));

        PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
        String privateKeyBytesBase64 = new String(Base64.encode(privateKeyBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));

        // test encryption
        String encrypted = encryptRSAToString(dataToEncrypt, publicKeyBytesBase64);

        // test decryption
        String decrypted = decryptRSAToString(encrypted, privateKeyBytesBase64);
    }

    public static KeyPair getKeyPair() {
        KeyPair kp = null;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            kpg.initialize(2048);
            kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return kp;
    }

    public static String encryptRSAToString(String clearText, String publicKey) {
        String encryptedBase64 = "";
        try {
            KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            KeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(publicKey.trim().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            Key key = keyFac.generatePublic(keySpec);

            // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING");
            // encrypt the plain text using the public key
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(clearText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            encryptedBase64 = new String(Base64.encode(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return encryptedBase64.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
    }

    public static String decryptRSAToString(String encryptedBase64, String privateKey) {

        String decryptedString = "";
        try {
            KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            KeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(privateKey.trim().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            Key key = keyFac.generatePrivate(keySpec);

            // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING");
            // encrypt the plain text using the public key
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

            byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.decode(encryptedBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
            decryptedString = new String(decryptedBytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return decryptedString;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you should use the same key pair to encrypt and decrypt the cipher. Referring to the JavaDoc:

```
 genKeyPair() This will generate a new key pair every time it is called.
```

Comment: @jaredzhang..I edited my code..but I get the same Exception..Please Review my Edited code..

Comment: @jaredzhang..I think you are right..But Problem is that Now I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException..

Comment: your new code seems unclear, please ensure the private key you are using to decrypt is the same you generated previously.

Comment: @jaredzhang..Hi..I have Edited my code again..so that..it seems clear to you..Please help me..and Thanks a lot..And see my question also..Exception I got is also Different as of now....

Comment: @jaredzhang So this can not be used to send data from one app to another as receiver app will call genKeyPair() and will create different key. Any solution?

Comment: @VirRajpurohit I think we should save the keys in andorid keystore

Answer (score 0):

when using RSAEcvypt method, its fill PublicKey and private key.
And when your Decrypt your generated byte[], your publicKey and privateKey being NULL.
Because of that you get this error.

You should use your keys static;

```
enter code here

KeyPairGenerator kpg;
KeyPair kp;
static PublicKey publicKey;
static PrivateKey privateKey;
byte [] encryptedBytes,decryptedBytes;
Cipher cipher,cipher1;
String encrypted,decrypted;
```

Comment: Those are class properties, as method accessing those keys are not static, thus it is not necessary for properties to be static. In fact it is a very bad choice to have static properties specially when you might need to create multiple instances of class with different data values.